# How to Manage Complicated Views Hierarchy using Auto-layout in iOS Sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, resize, autolayout, xcode6

I am working on an iOS application and it will be compatible for all devices iPhone 3.5, 4, 4.7, 5.5 inches and iPad also.
I am designing a screen it has 5 subviews, as i view this screen in different screen it does not resize properly.
I am using Auto-layout to manage that screen and I have set the every possible constraint to manage this screen.I have to manage the Subviews height and width as the devices changes.
Following are the steps taken care by me

**1)Set the Equal Height Constraint for all subviews**

**2)Equal Width Constraint for TopView1 and TopView2 set the High priority and set the proper  Horizontal spacing, Leading, trailing edges for these two top spaces accordingly.**

**3)Equal Width Constraint for MiddleView1 , MiddleView2 and MiddleView3 and  set the High priority and set the proper Horizontal spacing for these two and vertical spaces from TOpViews accordingly.**

**4)Set the Width Constraint for bottomView and  set the High priority and set the proper Horizontal spacing for these two and vertical spaces from MiddleViews and bottom spaces accordingly.**

Prior to this i have not used auto-layout in such complicated way.

Following are the screen shotes depict my problem.

**EDIT:**
@Ash Furrow please see attached a screen shotes with constraints.

I am laying out the base screen on **Any Width Any Height**

[image]
[image]

[image]

Please anybody suggest me how should i manage this view

Comment: If your target is a Universal App make sure you are always laying out your views in the "Any-Any" screen size initially. If you lay out your storyboard in any other size initially it will not resize properly...Redo the layout in "Any-Any" and it will work (It's hard to tell form the screenshots if this is what you did initially or not)

Comment: Yes, I am laying out this screen on WA-HA @DBoyer

Comment: It must be your constraints not being set properly...What I do when my constraints are not working is strip them all out and add them one view at a time, making sure that each view is behaving properly with different sizes before moving on to the next view. It usually takes me like 3 attempts to get it working right.

Comment: I have done everything best at my knowledge of Auto-layout.
Can you please help me on chat, if you OK.
I'll comment here Chat link after 40 minutes, gotta go for urgent work @DBoyer.

Comment: Yea sure..I will need to understand more about what you are trying to accomplish because the way the constraints you have set would make a very weird user experience if they worked right. Depending on what you want I would strongly suggest the use of collectionViews.

Comment: Hard to tell what's up without a sample Storyboard, but I didn't see anywhere where you set constraints on the leading/trailing space on the middle views.

Comment: @AshFurrow Thanks for your kind reply and sorry for my late reply i was busy in other assignments.I just edited my question and added a new Image which has all constraints.I am still not able to resize this screen properly

Comment: @DBoyer Thanks for your kind suggestion but i want to use it for my own interest as i want to explore the auto-layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Looking at what you've done and the feedback to your question, everything seems correct.

I think I see the problem. The issue doesn't appear to be with your storyboard ([here](https://github.com/kamarshad-dmi/LearningGit) in case anyone is interested), but rather the use of Xcode. Instead of changing the view controller's simulated "Size" metric, use the Assistant Editor to view a preview of whatever device you want. I've tried that, and ran the code, and in both cases they appear to work.

[image: Working]

So to recap, use the Preview in the Assistant Editor instead of changing the view controller's properties to resize a view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, But as you can see specially iPhone screen shot the GAP(vertical/horizontal space ) among the views must has less priority than to width and Height. I mean whenever view going to resize if proper space is not available then vertical/horizontal space must readjust.I need such kind of resizing effect.Could you please suggest me.